# Javascript function does not call window.open('tel: 12312312');

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to achieve is dial a number automatically on page load.

```
 <body onload="c()">
 <h1><a href="Tel: 8983823057">Call me if not called automatically!!!</a></h1>
  </body>   
  <script>

  function c()
  {
  window.open('tel: 12312312');  
  }

</script>
```

The code works fine on some browsers like parallel browser, but does not work on Chrome.
The problem is popup is blocked on Chrome, how do I call a number without popup

Answer (score 4):

Most browsers disallow opening new windows (calling `window.open`) on page load, because it's been badly abused in the past. Instead, new windows can only be opened in *direct* response to a user event (like a click).

Comment: So is their any other way to call a number on same page?

Comment: @OmkarFrozen: How about you just let the user call it by clicking, rather than trying to push it at them? (But answering the query: I don't know of any, but then, I haven't done a lot with `tel` links, either.)

Comment: Alternatively, if they've already arrived on this page because the user clicked, you could simply try `location.href = 'tel:whatever';` - redirections are much more allowed than popups are.

Comment: What I want to do is give a link on facebook post to call me... So I am actually redirecting the fb user and then call a number

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I tried it but same thing... the pop is blocked

Comment: @OmkarFrozen Fair enough - some (most?) browsers do tend to block cross-application redirects by default...

Comment: yes... it works on my chrome Desktop but does not work on mobile

Comment: any other way to atleast show the pop up to the user